# Does etherscan require the use of an api key

Tags: etherscan

I want to list transactions for accounts. However, I'm confused as to if etherscan requires an api key. One https://etherscan.io/apis, it says it you can create a api key to use with the api.

But if you check the following linked in the page: https://etherscan.io/apis#accounts

https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=account&action=balance&address=0xde0b295669a9fd93d5f28d9ec85e40f4cb697bae&tag=latest&apikey=YourApiKeyToken

You can clearly make the request. It even shows YourApiKeyToken as a place holder. But Removing it also allows me to view transactions. So, is an api key required?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wanna be able to push more transaction an API Key is required, from [I need an API key](https://etherscanio.freshdesk.com/support/solutions/articles/16000046110-i-need-an-api-key)

> As a developer, you will need to get an API key if you plan to push a lot more transactions once you have reached the limits. Without an API key, a rate limit of 5 requests/seconds is imposed so you may receive a HTTP 403 error if exceed this limit.

Comment: Hi, what is meant by push? I only plan on reading from the api. From what I could see, the api is read only anyway? So as long as I am not doing more than 5 requests a second,  I shouldn't require an api key right? This seems ok since I'm working on an app, so each user would have this limit.

Comment: @Sun What they mean by push is each time you do a request to the API, so yes if you stay under the 5 request per second you don't need the API key.